# Sending data from view to controller via ajax call not working in dotnet core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have converted my mvc 4 project to dotnet core, everything working fine but when i try to post data from view to controller via ajax call at that time data not able to pass in the controller

here is my code as bellow

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnAddZone', function () {
    debugger
    var Titles = $("input[name='TitleField']").map( function () {return $(this).val().trim(); }).get();

 var Name = $("#txtZoneName").val().trim();
    var Enabled = $("#checkboxG4").is(":checked")
    var ManualEntryAllow = $("#checkboxG5").is(":checked")
   var zone = {
       Name: Name,
       IsActive: Enabled,
       Titles: Titles,
       ManualEntryAllow: ManualEntryAllow
   }

   var a = JSON.stringify({ zone: zone });
   var url = '@Url.Action("AddZones", "Zone")';

   $.ajax({
       url: url,
       type: "POST",
       processData: false,
       contentType: "application/json",
       data: JSON.stringify({ zone: zone}),
       success: function (objStatus) {
           if (objStatus.IsSuccess) {
               oTable.fnFilter('');
               if (objStatus.IsSuccess) {
                   toastr.success(objStatus.Message)
                   $("#checkboxG4").prop("checked", false);
                   $("#checkboxG5").prop("checked", false);
                   $("#txtZoneName").val("");
                   $(".bd-example-modal-lg").modal("hide");
                   $("#tblAddTetxbox > tbody").html("");
               }
               else {
                   toastr.error(objStatus.Message)
               }
           }
       },
       error: function (reponse) {
           window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Login","Account")';
           //toastr.error("Error Occured , Please try again.");
       }
    });

});
```

Comment: What error are you getting can you check in network tab

Comment: Can you show the code in your controller ?

Comment: Thank you for reply @TonyNgo i have resloved my issue by passing the [FromBody] in my controller before model passing, Its look like public ActionResult add([FromBody]Model model)